# Kendo Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'table' of undefined

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

this is my kendo dropdown code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("AttributeTypeId")
                  .DataTextField("AttributeTypeName")
                  .DataValueField("AttributeTypeId")
                   .DataSource(source =>
                   {
                       source.Read(read =>
                       {
                           read.Action("my_method", "my_controller");
                       });
                   })
                )
```

this is my script:

```
<script>
      $(document.body).keydown(function (e) {
          if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 87) {
              $("\\#AttributeTypeId").data("kendoGrid").table.focus();
          }
        });
 </script>
```

i am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'table' of undefined
```

any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.data("kendoDropDownList")` ?

Comment: yes, this solved my error.